# Компьютер «забирает» на себя доступ к сайту

Tags: squid, debian, proxy

Есть локалка с выходом в интернет через прозрачный squid3. В локалке есть ноут, который когда открывает один конкретный сайт, остальные компьютеры этот сайт открыть уже не могут. При этом пингуется адрес сайта без проблем.Конфиг кальмара сделал уже минимальным:

```
http_port 192.168.0.1:3128 transparentcache_mem 87040cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid3/cache 20000 16 256acl allowed_hosts src 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255acl allow_ports port 80 8080acl allow_ports port 21 23 122 70 210 110 25 5190acl SSL_ports port 443 563 910 8443 4500acl CONNECT method CONNECTconnect_timeout 240 secondshttp_access deny !allow_portshttp_access deny CONNECT !SSL_portshttp_access allow localhosthttp_access allow allow_portshttp_access allow SSL_portshttp_access deny all
```

Может есть у кого хоть какие предположения, в чем может быть проблема и как отследить можно на сервере (Debian 6.0) что происходит в момент обращения к нему в этой ситуации?

Comment: > остальные компьютеры этот сайт открыть уже не могутА это как? Получаете какую-то конкретную ошибку? Ничего не получаете? Что в логах ([почитать где логи][1])? Что за такой хитрый сайт - какой-то определенный или любой?Больше подробностей...  [1]: https://www.google.by/search?q=%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5+squid+%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82+%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8&oq=%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5+squid+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.12008j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: После долгого ожидания получаю ошибку 110: Запрашиваемый URL не может быть доставленСайт один конкретный, причем из других мест он открывается нормально. В логах ничего не нашел, пишутся только успешные запросы

Comment: А что, если другой комп в сети откроет этот сайт? Будет то же самое? Логи кальмара - в студию, а там попробуем разобраться!